# Changing the key of a practice chanter

Tags: tuning, key, bagpipes

There are tunable practice chanters for sale that some say can be retuned from the key of A to C. Would love to hear from anybody who has tried / done this to learn what's involved.

Comment: I always found bagpipes to be close to Bb. But if the chanters changed, what happens to the drones?

Comment: @Tim Bagpipes are theoretically tuned to 'A', except their A is about 459 Hz, much closer to everyone else's B-flat. https://bagpipe.news/2020/04/28/aspects-of-tuning-pitch-scale-and-drones/

Comment: @PiedPiper - yes, Bb is as close as I could ever get on (mainly) New Year's Eve gigs!

Comment: Tunable chanters have some sort of tuning slide. A range of about a semitone might be possible, but a minor third would be impossible.